# Asynchronously iterate as collection grows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-loop

I'm iterating over an array and performing some iteration within that loop that may add something to the array, causing the loop to last longer. (I'm aware one shouldn't change the object over which one is iterating, but bear with me.)

I'm using the array as sort of a queue to traverse a tree breadth first.

This would work just fine, except each iteration is an ajax call, and therefore asynchronous, meaning the loop is long over before the callback queue is dequeued. This means that my collection doesn't grow while I'm looping, and the loop ends up being too short.

My first instinct would be to use a closure to capture the collection for every iteration, but that wouldn't help the fact that the collection erroneously starts growing *after* looping.

Another idea I had was to check if a library like async supports what I'm trying to do, but I'm not familiar with it and haven't been able to find it in their docs.

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (some condition) {
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
      array.push(data);  // this happens to late since this function is asynchronous
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use deferred object and after all requests have been resolved, append the data to the array

```
var promises = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (some condition) {
    promises.push($http.get(url));
  }
}

$q.all(promises).then(function(data){
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       array.push(data[i]);
   }
});
```

Read more about `$q` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Does `$q.all` run every time all promises in the array are resolved? That array may grow again after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend promises for this:

```
var all = Promise.all(arr.map(function(x){ //$q.all can also work, see below
   if(condition) { //whatever your condition is
      //can be promises ($http.get() returns a promise) or non-promise values
      return $http.get(); //instead of pushing it
   } else {
      //same as above
      return value; //instead of pushing it
   }
}));
 /* all promise which represents the eventual resolution 
    of all your returned values */
```

You are free to do whatever you want with the promise afterwards.

```
all.then(function(data){
  //data is your array with all your http responses
});
```

**A concern about $q.all and non-promise values**

Looks like `$q.all` takes an array of promises; it doesn't say it converts non-promise values into resolved promise values. If you plan on using `$q.all` with non-promise values then I'd recommend you being explicit just to be safe and covert non-promise values into resolved promises with that value.

```
$q.resolve(value);
```